# $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{-3/x}}{x^2}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{-3/x}}{x^2}$$
I used L'Hôpital's rule once and got up to $\frac3{2x^3e^{3/x}}$. I then rearranged the function to get $\frac3{(e^{3/x}/(1/2x^3))}$. From here on I used L'Hôpital's rule, rearranged the function for about $3$ times before I gave up. Can somebody pinpoint my mistake and show me the complete working? I apologise for the confusing formulas as I do know how to type them out in the right format yet.

Comment: I suggest in general to avoid l'Hospital when possible or use only it to double check the result. Try always to use standard limits, squeeze therorem and related, you will get a deeper knowledge and feeling about how limit work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for $x=\frac1y$ with $y\to +\infty$

$$\frac{e^{-\frac3x}}{x^2}=y^2e^{-3y}=\frac{y^2}{e^{3y}}\to 0$$

indeed, without l'Hospital, we can simply observe that eventually $e^{3y}>y^3$ then

$$0<\frac{y^2}{e^{3y}}<\frac{y^2}{y^3}=\frac1y\to 0$$

therefore the limit follow by squeeze theorem.

Comment: Gimusi.Very nice! :)

Comment: hm but when we plug in for e.g. $x=0.0000001$ in $$e^{\frac{-x}{x^2}}$$  we get $$10^{14}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sorry I didn't recognize your limit with that given in the OP

Comment: i meant $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{e^{-3/x}}{x^2}$$  the result $0$ is right